# $_GET before session_start(), to retrieve session name

Tags: php, session

I am trying to pass a session name to a page, via url, and retrieve it using $_GET, to then set the session name, then I can start the correct session.

However I get errors, and a blank sessionName..

Example:

```
$sessionName = $_GET['sessionName'];
session_name($sessionName);
session_start($sessionName);
```

Any idea why this doesnt work? If I take out session_start and echo sessionName, it functions ok and echoes the session name.

Comment: This seems like it would have a high potential for session hijacking...

Comment: This isn't the best idea in the word. Since `$_SESSION` is a super-global why do you need to pass it in the url to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with me:

```
$_GET['sessionName'] = 'MYSESSION';
$sessionName = $_GET['sessionName'];
session_name($sessionName);
session_start($sessionName);
echo 'Session name: '.session_name().'<br>Session id: '.session_id();
```

output:

```
Session name: MYSESSION
Session id: rtf3pjftivccsbbduplqcgk1j0
```